# How to get environment variable from a user account in R and Python?

Tags: r, python-3.x

I have run the following command in the cmd prompt.

```
setx SPARK_HOME E:\Raja\Installed_Software\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7
```

It creates the `SPARK_HOME` in my account (not in the system account, I guess). I know the following codes picks up the SPARK_HOME from System account.

**In R:**

```
> Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME") 
[1] ""
```

**In Python**

```
import os
os.environ.get('SPARK_HOME', None)
```

Is there any way to get the `SPARK_HOME` from my account? Thanks.

Comment: You really need to spend some time reading about environment variable scoping and how they are referenced from processes.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft documentation for [setx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx) says:

> Setx writes variables to the master environment in the registry.
>   Variables set with setx variables are available in future command
>   windows only, not in the current command window.

so if you are starting or running R from the same cmd window as the `setx` command was run in it won't work.  You must start a new cmd window.

You could consider setting this in your .Rprofile or .Renviron files if you want it to persist or use `set` (as @alex_danielssen points out in his answer) if you don't need persistance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the variable to be immediately accessible from the current command window, use the SET command:

```
set SPARK_HOME='E:\Raja\Installed_Software\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7'
```

As G. Grothendieck points out, the setx command will only work in subsequent cmd windows.